# Are the ACM Java Libraries used in real life?

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

Is the ACM JTF's Java libraries used in real life, or just prepared for students to make their study less complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ACM Java Task Force charter](http://jtf.acm.org/):

> To review the Java language, APIs, and tools from the perspective of introductory computing education and to develop a stable collection of pedagogical resources that will make it easier to teach Java to first-year computing students without having those students overwhelmed by its complexity.

So I doubt any of their code is actually intended for use in "real life" projects...